# Why might a dedupe rule fail to deliver results, or result in server crashing?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Title pretty much says it all and this question is being asked so it can be found easily and we can track progress in JIRA

Answer (score 1):

Having found the users have repeatedly misconfigured Dedupe / Matching Rules with a Weight Threshold of zero or NULL, both of which (I think) can result in a search of every record against every other record, I believe that Save should not be possible with zero/null.

[Jira here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20216)